# Print help if no positional argument?

Tags: python, argparse

I'm making a pretty simple script which takes the following parameters:

```
-p --port integer, optional, default 5050
-f --fork boolean, optional, default False
action string, required, needs to be either start or stop
```

I've tried implementing this in argparse, but it's not printing help when action string isn't provided, it's just failing all ugly-like:

```
usage: __init__.py [-h] [-p PORT] [-f] {start,stop}
__init__.py: error: argument action: invalid choice: '__init__.py' (choose from 'start', 'stop')
```

Even when I pass "start" or "stop", it fails with the same message. Here's my code:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Start or stop the server.",
    epilog="If you don't know what you're doing, run. Run for your life.\n")
parser.add_argument("-p", "--port", type=int, nargs=1, default=5050,
    dest="port", help="The port to run the server on.")
parser.add_argument("-f", "--fork", action="store_true", default=False,
    dest="fork", help="Fork to background? Default is false.")
parser.add_argument("action", type=str, choices=("start","stop"), help="Whether to 'start' or 'stop' the server.")
```

What am I doing wrong here? Hopefully my intentions are pretty clear from my code.

Comment: How are you calling `__init__.py`? Somehow `__init.py__` is being supplied as the first argument, as if you were calling `python __init__.py __init__.py`.

Comment: How are you calling `parser.parse_args()`? If I say `parser.parse_args(['start'])`, I get back a `Namespace` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of Python are you using? When I run your code with 2.7.1 it works fine.

```
$ ./t stop
$ ./t start
$ ./t -f start
$ ./t -f stop
$ ./t -f
usage: someprog [-h] [-p PORT] [-f] {start,stop}
someprog: error: too few arguments
$ ./t -f -p 8080
usage: someprog [-h] [-p PORT] [-f] {start,stop}
someprog: error: too few arguments
$ ./t -f -p 8080 start
```

One tip, if you specify 'prog' in the ctor you can override it using **init**.py as the filename

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    prog="someprog",
    description="Start or stop the server.",
    epilog="If you don't know what you're doing, run. Run for your life.\n"
)
```

Also, it *is* printing usage, but not the long help.. You could do something like this to make things a little more obvious..

```
try:
    parser.parse_args()
except Exception e:
    print "************************"
    parser.print_help()
    print "************************"
```

Comment: My bad, I was passing `sys.argv` instead of `sys.argv[1:]`.

Answer (score 2):

When invalid arguments are supplied, the [argparse module](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html) is designed to print a usage message and a description of the problem then exit, which is precisely what is happening in your example.

If you want it to print a help message instead, you'll need to handle this case yourself. For example, this code will print the help message in the event that no action is provided:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Start or stop the server.",
    epilog="If you don't know what you're doing, run. Run for your life.\n",
    prog="myserver")
parser.add_argument("-p", "--port", type=int, nargs=1, default=5050,
    dest="port", help="The port to run the server on.")
parser.add_argument("-f", "--fork", action="store_true", default=False,
    dest="fork", help="Fork to background? Default is false.")
parser.add_argument("action", nargs="?", type=str, choices=("start","stop"),
    help="Whether to 'start' or 'stop' the server.")

args = parser.parse_args()
if args.action is None:
    parser.print_help()
    sys.exit(1)
```

If I run this with no action, I get:

```
$ python s.py
usage: myserver [-h] [-p PORT] [-f] [{start,stop}]

Start or stop the server.

positional arguments:
  {start,stop}          Whether to 'start' or 'stop' the server.

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -p PORT, --port PORT  The port to run the server on.
  -f, --fork            Fork to background? Default is false.

If you don't know what you're doing, run. Run for your life.
```

However, if I run this with an invalid action, or an invalid argument, then it reverts to the intended behaviour of the argparse module:

```
 $ python s.py not_valid
usage: myserver [-h] [-p PORT] [-f] [{start,stop}]
myserver: error: argument action: invalid choice: 'not_valid' (choose from 'start', 'stop')
```

Comment: Is it possible to print help when it is run with an invalid action or with an invalid argument?